# Use inheritance for very similar controllers in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I have a rails app with two controllers that have very similar behaviors. 
One is a UsersController related to the concept of Hotel, the other is also named UsersController but related to the concept of association, so it is stored in a folder association :`class Api::V1::Association::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseController`

These controllers have very similar behaviors, methods with minor differences (they rely on different database tables for certain variables...). I was reading about inheritance and thought that it could be interesting to make the `Association::UsersController` inherit from the `UsersController`. Do you think this could be the right thing to do in my case ? For example I have been trying to rewritte the method invite of `Association::UsersController` to use inheritance but I am a bit confused on how to do it. Could you tell me how you would rewrite this method if the `Association::UsersController`inherits from the `usersController`. Here how both controllers look like :

users_controller.rb :

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseController
  skip_after_action :verify_authorized, only: [:invite, :update_specific, :show]
  before_action :set_user, except: [:invite, :index, :update_specific]
  before_action :set_account, only: [:index, :invite, :show]

  # creates user linked to account / only account owner can create users linked to account
  # input account_id & email
  def invite
    unless current_user.id != @account.admin_user_id
      user_already_exists_or_email_blank?
      set_new_user
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        set_hotels_access
        save_user_and_send_invitation_email
      end
    else
      render_error("not_admin")
    end
  end

  def show
    if ((current_user == @user) || (@account.admin == current_user))
    else
      render_error("unauthorized")
    end
  end

  # admin can update employee or manager
  def update_specific
    @user_to_update = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user_to_update.account != current_user.created_account
      render_error("unauthorized")
    else
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        update_user_and_hotels_access
      end
    end
  end

  # update self
  def update
    authorize @user
    if @user.update(user_params)
      render_success("updated")
    else
      render_error("")
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize @user
    if @user.destroy
      render json: {message: "User successfully destroyed"}
    else
      render json: {error: "There was an error please try again"}
    end
  end
  # envoyer account params
  def index
    if (current_user.created_account == @account) || ((current_user.account == @account) && (current_user.status == "manager"))
      @users = policy_scope(User).where(account: @account)
      @admin = @account.admin
      render json: {users: @users, admin: @admin}
    else
      render json: {message: "Unauthorized"}
    end
  end

  # unlincks user from account
  #input user_id
  def unlinck
    authorize @user
    @user.account = nil
    if @user.save && @user.hotels.delete_all.nil?
      render json: {user: @user}
    else
      render_error("db")
    end
  end

  private

  def user_already_exists_or_email_blank?
    if User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
      render_error("mail_exists") and return
    elsif params[:user][:email].blank?
      render_error("empty_email") and return
    end
  end

  def set_new_user
    password = SecureRandom.hex
    invitation_token = SecureRandom.uuid
    @user = User.new(first_name: params[:user][:first_name], last_name: params[:user][:last_name], telephone: params[:user][:telephone], account_id: params[:user][:account_id], email: params[:user][:email], status: params[:user][:status], password: password, password_confirmation: password, invitation_token: invitation_token, invitation_created_at: Time.now, role: "hotel")
  end

  def set_hotels_access
    if params[:hotel_access].first == "all"
      @hotels = @account.hotels
    else
      @hotels = Hotel.where(id: params[:hotel_access])
    end
  end

  def save_user_and_send_invitation_email
    if @user.save && @user.hotels << @hotels
      if UserMailer.send_invitation(@user, params[:app_base_url]).deliver_now
        @user.invitation_sent_at = Time.now
        if @user.save
          render_success("mail_sent")
        else
          render_error("db")
        end
      else
        render_error("mail_processing")
      end
    else
      render_error("db")
    end
  end

  def update_user_and_hotels_access
    @hotels = Hotel.where(id: params[:hotel_access])
    if @user_to_update.hotels.destroy_all
      if @user_to_update.hotels << @hotels
        if @user_to_update.update(user_params)
          render json: {message: "User successfully updated"}
        else
          render_error("db")
        end
      else
        render("db")
      end
    else
      render_error("db")
    end
  end

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_account
    if params[:account_id]
      @account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
    elsif params[:user][:account_id]
      @account = Account.find(params[:user][:account_id])
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :email,
      :account_id,
      :first_name,
      :last_name,
      :telephone,
      :position,
      :status,
      :user_id
    )
  end

  def render_error(error_type)
    case error_type
      when "not_admin"
         render json: {error: "You are not allowed to create a user for this account"}
      when "mail_exists"
         render json: {error: "Please fill the email field and try again"}
      when "empty_email"
        render json: {error: "Please fill the email field and try again"}
      when "mail_processing"
         render json: { error: "We couldnt send an email to your invitee. Please try again" }
      when "db"
        render json: {error: "An error occured. Please try again"}
      when "unauthorized"
        render json: {error: "Unauthorized"}
      else
        render json: { errors: @user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def render_success(success_type)
    case success_type
      when "mail_sent"
        render json: { success: "An email was sent to your collaborator asking him to join your Quickbed team." }
      when "password_changed"
        render json: {success: "Your password was successfully changed"}
      when "updated"
        render json: {success: "Your infos were successfully updated"}
    end
  end

end
```

association/users_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::Association::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseController
  skip_after_action :verify_authorized, only: [:invite, :update_specific, :show]
  before_action :set_user, except: [:invite, :index, :update_specific]
  before_action :set_account_asso, only: [:index, :show, :invite]

  # creates user linked to account / only account owner can create users linked to account
  # input account_id & email
  def invite
    unless current_user.id != @account_asso.admin_user_id
      user_already_exists_or_email_blank?
      set_new_user
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        set_offices_access
        save_user_and_send_invitation_email
      end
    else
      render_error("not_admin")
    end
  end

  def show
    if ((current_user == @user) || (@account_asso.admin == current_user))
    else
      render_error("unauthorized")
    end
  end

  # admin can update employee or manager
  def update_specific
    @user_to_update = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user_to_update.account != current_user.created_account
      render_error("unauthorized")
    else
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        update_user_and_offices_access
      end
    end
  end

  # update self
  def update
    authorize @user
    if @user.update(user_params)
      render_success("updated")
    else
      render_error("db")
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize @user
    if @user.destroy
      render json: {message: "User successfully destroyed"}
    else
      render_error("db")
    end
  end
  # envoyer account params
  def index
    if (current_user.created_account_asso == @account_asso) || ((current_user.account_asso == @account_asso) && (current_user.status == "manager"))
      @users = policy_scope(User).where(account_asso: @account_asso)
      @admin = @account_asso.admin
      render json: {users: @users, admin: @admin}
    else
      render_error("unauthorized")
    end
  end

  # unlincks user from account
  #input user_id
  def unlinck
    authorize @user
    @user.account_asso = nil
    if @user.save && @user.offices.delete_all.nil?
      render json: {user: @user}
    else
      render_error("db")
    end
  end

  private

  def user_already_exists_or_email_blank?
    if User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
      render_error("mail_exists") and return
    elsif params[:user][:email].blank?
      render_error("empty_email") and return
    end
  end

  def set_new_user
    password = SecureRandom.hex
    invitation_token = SecureRandom.uuid
    @user = User.new(first_name: params[:user][:first_name], last_name: params[:user][:last_name], telephone: params[:user][:telephone], account_asso_id: params[:user][:account_asso_id], email: params[:user][:email], status: params[:user][:status], password: password, password_confirmation: password, invitation_token: invitation_token, invitation_created_at: Time.now, role: "asso")
  end

  def set_offices_access
    if params[:office_access].first == "all"
      @offices = account_asso.offices
    else
      @offices = Office.where(id: params[:office_access])
    end
  end

  def save_user_and_send_invitation_email
    if @user.save &&  @user.offices << offices
      if UserMailer.send_invitation(@user, params[:app_base_url]).deliver_now
        @user.invitation_sent_at = Time.now
        if @user.save
          render_success("mail_sent")
        else
          render_error("db")
        end
      else
        render_error("mail_processing")
      end
    else
      render_error("db")
    end
  end

  def update_user_and_offices_access
   @offices = Office.where(id: params[:office_access])
    if @user_to_update.offices.destroy_all
      if @user_to_update.offices << @offices
        if @user_to_update.update(user_params)
          render json: {message: "User successfully updated"}
        else
          render_error("db")
        end
      else
        render("db")
      end
    else
      render_error("db")
    end
  end

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_account_asso
    if params[:account_asso_id]
      @account_asso = AccountAsso.find(params[:account_asso_id])
    elsif params[:user][:account_asso_id]
      @account_asso = AccountAsso.find(params[:user][:account_asso_id])
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :email,
      :account_id,
      :first_name,
      :last_name,
      :telephone,
      :position,
      :status,
      :user_id
    )
  end

  def render_error(error_type)
    case error_type
      when "not_admin"
         render json: {error: "You are not allowed to create a user for this account"}
      when "mail_exists"
         render json: {error: "Please fill the email field and try again"}
      when "empty_email"
        render json: {error: "Please fill the email field and try again"}
      when "mail_processing"
         render json: { error: "We couldnt send an email to your invitee. Please try again" }
      when "db"
        render json: {error: "An error occured. Please try again"}
      when "unauthorized"
        render json: {error: "Unauthorized"}
      else
        render json: { errors: @user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def render_success(success_type)
    case success_type
      when "mail_sent"
        render json: { success: "An email was sent to your collaborator asking him to join your Quickbed team." }
      when "password_changed"
        render json: {success: "Your password was successfully changed"}
      when "updated"
        render json: {success: "Your infos were successfully updated"}
    end
  end

end
```

Maybe I should rewritte the `usersController` linked to the concept of Hotel or maybe I should create a third `superusersController`from which both the usersController linked to the concept of hotel and the usersController linked to the concept of Association would inherit ? Could you help me find the best fit to my situation ?

Comment: I'd focus on fixing the controller code first; those methods are *far* too nested and almost impossible to reason about. *Then* see if there's shared behavior, *then* determine *how* to share that behavior.

Comment: Yes, there is a ton of useless duplication between these two controllers. That said, I'm not sure the issue is so much that as your data model or how you're thinking about it. The "best" way to proceed likely goes beyond ripping out some dupe behavior into a super-class, but it's certainly a place to start. But still: this code is pretty rough to read.

Comment: thanks @DaveNewton, I am following your advice and starting to extract some code into methods

Comment: @DaveNewton I have rewritten the code from the controllers, mainly invite and update_specific methods by extracting bunch of codes in private methods. Do you have other suggestions to make the code of these controllers cleaner ?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at Service Objects. They are just plain old Ruby objects. You can extract your `invite` method into something like `UsersService#invite` then call it from both controllers. Differences in logic can be handled by passing it a parameter in which context it runs in (users or associations)

Comment: thanks @Ruslan. So you dont think it could be a good choice to use inheritance ?

Comment: @Dave Probably not in this case. Unless you are planning to share this code with many other controllers. Anything is a solution if it works, but for this case mixins or service objects should do the trick